# Getting WebDAV content via Delphi and Indy 10 TIdHTTP

Tags: delphi, http, webdav, indy, indy10

Looking on the Delphi newsgroups, it appears the best way to GET content from a WebDAV server is to use the built in TIdHTTP.Get.  While doing this, the result is HTML and I just want to make sure that this is the best way to retrieve data about the directories and files.  If so, then I'll parse it out, but I just want to make sure there isn't a cleaner way that may have JUST the file/folder information for me...  And no, as of now I am not looking to use any other components for this.

Comment: your title mentions `TIdWebDAV` but your question asks about `TIdHTTP` instead. Have you actually looked at using `TIdWebDAV` yet? The WebDav protocol uses XML, not HTML. You will have to parse the XML yourself, however you can use XPath to simplify your parsing to extract the info you need.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other option built into TidHTTP that will parse the webdav response into some collection and/or list-like, could be wrong tho.

Comment: There is no WebDav XML parser in Indy. `TIdWebDAV` is a `TIdHTTP` wrapper that simplifies sending WebDav commands, but you have to parse the output yourself.

Comment: Remy - yes, that is what I meant.  I was actually referring to your newsgroup post saying that to retrieve data you simply use the TIdHTTP.Get since that is what TIdWebDAV descends from.  However, the WebDAV server I am accessing is definitely returning HTML ("<html><head><title>Directory listing for/</title>") and NOT XML unfortunately.  That is why I was double checking...

Comment: After looking at this some more, let me clarify - I guess if I use the Get on a FILE, then I probably get just the contents, which is fine.  What I really need to know is, how do I get a COLLECTION?  When I "Get" a "Folder" I am getting an HTML representation of it.  I would like an XML list of the items in a collection, but I am unsure how the best way to go about getting that.

Comment: I think I figured it out - I did a PropFile with allprop and a depth of 1.  That seems to give me everything in a current "directory" and I can drill down with that.  Unless there is a nicer way (or if I am not using PropFind correctly), I will consider this closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own: I think I figured it out - I did a PropFile with allprop and a depth of 1. That seems to give me everything in a current "directory" and I can drill down with that. Unless there is a nicer way (or if I am not using PropFind correctly), I will consider this closed.  References that were helpful:

- Spec: http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc2518.html
- XML schema: http://code.google.com/p/sardine/source/browse/trunk/webdav.xsd?r=123